# ¿como mantener el dominio en un sitio web en IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dominio, windows-server

la situación es al siguiente, tengo un servidor Windows Server y quiero publicar una aplicación web ahí en IIS, tengo un dominio en godaddy, ahí ya configure para que los DNS apunten a la dirección IP publica del servidor (WS), en el momento cuando escribo el dominio en el navegador me muestra el sitio web que se publico en el servidor, pero el inconveniente es que no me mantiene el nombre del dominio en el navegador sino que me lo cambia por la dirección IP publica del servidor.

Como dato curioso, en el *site Bindings* si agrego en el *host name* solo mi dominio no encuentra el sitio el navegador, pero si lo dejo vació si lo alcanza

¿Como hago para que al encontrar el sitio en el navegador me mantenga el nombre del dominio y no me lo cambie por la dirección IP publica?

Comment: Encontraste solución a esto? Yo tengo el mismo problema... Gracias!